# How to generate vectors with programming

Tags: matrix, programming, vector

I want to generate all possible vectors programicaly with entrys in $\Bbb Z_4$:
$$A_j:=\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\ x_2\end{bmatrix}, \qquad x_i\in \{0,1,2,3\}, j=1,2,\cdots 16.$$

Comment: See first hit of the search for keys [*all possible vectors*](https://reference.wolfram.com/search/?q=all%20possible%20vectors) in the doc center.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`Tuples`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tuples.html).

```
Tuples[{0,1,2,3}, {2}]
```

Comment: Thanks @Szabolcs. My purpose of this question was the detailed code of `Tuples`.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use Outer, since this is a kind of outer product with the function List:

```
elem = {0, 1, 2, 3}; Flatten[Outer[List, elem, elem], 1]
```